# Результат выполнения метода shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale

Tags: android, android-permissions

Метод `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` возвращает `boolean`, и вот всё, что написано по поводу возвращаемого этим методом значения [в официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String)):

> boolean | Whether you can show permission rationale UI.

В книге Марка Мерфи про результат выполнения этого метода написано следующее:

> This will return true if the user had previously declined to grant you
>   permission, in cases where Android thinks that the user might benefit
>   from learning a bit more about why you need the permission.

Т.е. этот метод возвращает `true`, если пользователь ранее отклонил запрос на разрешение, **в случаях, когда Android думает, что пользователь может получить пользу от информации, зачем нужно разрешение**.

Меня заинтересовало, что это могут быть за случаи. И по этому поводу я нашла также следующее замечание [в официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

> If the user turned down the permission request in the past and chose
>   the Don't ask again option in the permission request system dialog,
>   this method returns false. The method also returns false if a device
>   policy prohibits the app from having that permission

Т.е. этот метод должен возвращать `true`, если приложение запрашивало это разрешение ранее, и пользователь отклонил запрос, и возвращать `false`, если ранее пользователь при запросе разрешения выбрал параметр "Не спрашивать снова" или если политика устройства запрещает приложению иметь такое разрешение.

И вот меня интересует, вышеописанное замечание перечисляет все случаи, когда "Android может думать, что пользователь может получить пользу от информации, зачем нужно разрешение"?

И что значит "если политика устройства запрещает приложению иметь такое разрешение"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*По моему примерно так, могу ошибаться.*

> Т.е. этот метод возвращает true, если пользователь ранее отклонил
>   запрос на разрешение, в случаях, когда Android думает, что
>   пользователь может получить пользу от информации, зачем нужно
>   разрешение.
>
> Меня заинтересовало, что это могут быть за случаи.

Пользователь установил приложение, к примеру, для рисования, и оно (приложение) запрашивает разрешения на локацию или в контакты. Пользователь задается вопросом "Зачем ему это?". Приложение может вывести объяснение необходимости этого разрешения. Пользователь не принимает объяснение.

Далее вызывается метод `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()`. И вот тут `этот метод возвращает true, если пользователь ранее отклонил запрос на разрешение, в случаях, когда Android думает, что пользователь может получить пользу от информации, зачем нужно разрешение.`

> И что значит "если политика устройства запрещает приложению иметь
>   такое разрешение"?

Скорее всего речь идет о случаях, когда приложение реализует [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) , становится "[владельцем устройства](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#DeviceOwner)"  и определяет "политику устройства".